# Qtile How to change screen placement

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've setup Qtile and have a problem with screen placement. I have two physical monitors and my main monitor is placed to the left but Qtile recognizes it to the right. Now I could just physically change position but my main monitor is of better quality and I would prefer it to be placed to the left ie in front of me.

From the [docs](http://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/_modules/libqtile/config.html#Screen) i find the following var in the Screen class:

```
class Screen(CommandObject):
...
        # if one screen is "right" of the other
        self.x = x
```

If I understand it correctly I could set x=0 for left placement for one screen and x=1920 (1080p monitors) for the other screen and they should be placed left or right based on that. In the config this would look like:

```
screens = [Screen(x=0, top=bar.Bar...), Screen(x=1920)]
```

I tried this but it does not work.

Now reading the [docs further](http://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/ref/commands.html?highlight=screen#screen) they do say "Also, x, y, width, and height aren’t specified usually unless you are using ‘fake screens’." so above probably is not expected to work with real monitors.

Is there some way in Qtile to specify which of the two physical monitors I have is the left or right?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Qtile issue so much as a problem with your Xorg configuration. You probably want to look up `xorg multi monitor <your GPU brand>` for more information. For example, my setup which uses an NVIDIA gpu has this in my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia.conf` file (partially generated by nvidia-settings program):

```
Section "Screen"
...
    Option  "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}, DP-2: 1920x1080_144 +0+540"
...
```

The `+1920+0` and `+0+540` parts set absolute coordinates of where the monitors are relative to each other.

Comment: Great, was not aware of this and thanks for sending me to this path. I'm sure I'll figure out a solution with this tip. [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Using_.conf_files) has a good tutorial that explains this further and I'll take a look there.

Comment: Because of the tip above and understanding where the issue lies I came across a app called [arandr](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/) which solved my problem so adding it here as a tip.